# Minor Typo in the FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was just scanning the FAQ and saw this typo:

`3.Is it actual code from a project rather **then** pseudo-code or example code?`

I know it's not a big deal, but I am just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. Thank you for the report.